# Does the WebAii framework support a page class structure in the way that WatiN does?

Tags: automated-tests, watin, webaii

I am evaluating a couple of different frameworks for test automation. One of the things I really like about WatiN is the page model for abstracting page code from your tests.

Watin Example for a login Page:

```
public class AVLoginPage : Page
{
    public TextField Email
    {
        get { return Document.TextField(Find.ById("UserLogin_UserName")); }
    }

    public TextField Password
    {
        get { return Document.TextField(Find.ById("UserLogin_Password")); }
    }

    public Button LoginBtn
    {
        get { return Document.Button(Find.ById("UserLogin_LoginButton")); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Enters the email and loging in to the corresponding boxes and clicks the login button.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="email"></param>
    /// <param name="password"></param>
    public void Login(string email, string password)
    {
        Email.TypeText(email);
        Password.TypeText(password);
        LoginBtn.Click();
    }
}
```

Can I do something like this with WebAii?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is the approach I have started to take using the WebAii libraries:

My test code looks like:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Login_inValid_Combination_WebAii()
{
    Manager.LaunchNewBrowser(BrowserType.Safari);
    ActiveBrowser.NavigateTo(baseUrl + "login.aspx");

    LoginPage.Login("test@roger.com", "123421343414",ActiveBrowser);
    string expectedMsg = "Email address or password is incorrect.";
    string actualMsg  = LoginPage.GetError(ActiveBrowser);

    Assert.IsTrue(actualMsg.Contains(expectedMsg));


}
```

I then have a library:

```
using ArtOfTest.WebAii.Controls.HtmlControls;
using ArtOfTest.WebAii.Controls.HtmlControls.HtmlAsserts;
using ArtOfTest.WebAii.Core;
using ArtOfTest.WebAii.ObjectModel;
using ArtOfTest.WebAii.TestAttributes;
using ArtOfTest.WebAii.TestTemplates;
using ArtOfTest.WebAii.Win32.Dialogs;

using ArtOfTest.WebAii.Silverlight;
using ArtOfTest.WebAii.Silverlight.UI;

namespace WebAIIPageLibrary
{
    public class LoginPage : BaseTest
    {

        public static void Login(string email, string password, Browser passedBrowser )
        {

            passedBrowser.Find.ById<HtmlInputText>("UserLogin_UserName").Text = email;
            passedBrowser.Find.ById<HtmlInputPassword>("UserLogin_Password").Text = password;
            passedBrowser.Find.ById<HtmlInputSubmit>("UserLogin_LoginButton").Click();
        }

        public static string GetError(Browser passedBrowser)
        {
            ReadOnlyCollection<HtmlDiv> div = passedBrowser.Find.AllByTagName<HtmlDiv>("div");
            string errorMsg = "";
            foreach(HtmlDiv s in div)
            {
                if (s.CssClass == "error")
                {
                    errorMsg = s.InnerText;
                    break;
                }
            }

            return errorMsg;         
        }

        public static string GetDashboardTitle(Browser passedBrowser)
        {
            return passedBrowser.Window.Caption;
        }
    }
}
```

This allows me to abstract the actions on the page from the test code itself.

Answer (score 0):

Telerik Testing Framework (formerly called WebAii) does not include any recording capabilities. To get full recording and automatic Page class abstraction the way I think you want it you need to purchase a license to [Test Studio](http://www.telerik.com/automated-testing-tools.aspx) (or [Test Studio Express](http://www.telerik.com/products/test-studio-express.aspx) which comes with Ultimate Collection).

If you want to hand code your own abstractions, you are welcome to do so following the [Find Expression documentation](http://www.telerik.com/automated-testing-tools/support/documentation/user-guide/telerik-testing-framework/intermediate-topics/element-identification/find-expressions.aspx). Also (not currently documented, but we're working on it) is the [Find()] attribute you can use along with Find Expressions. This attribute replaces the [old FindParam attribute](http://www.telerik.com/automated-testing-tools/support/documentation/user-guide/telerik-testing-framework/advanced-topics/attribute-extensions.aspx). The FindParam attribute only work on HTML elements while the new Find attribute works on both HTML and XAML elements.

Comment: I actually was not asking about recording capabilities.  Thanks.  I did figure something out though.